# Why do I see other repositories when running git status on project I deleted from GitHub?

Tags: git, debugging, github

1. I manually deleted a repository in GitHub via their website.
2. I also ran `rm -rf .git` in my project thinking it would wipe out anything git related.
3. I ran `git status` in my project just to see if anything would come up in terms of git.
4. To my surprise, I see a list of projects that aren't on my GitHub account anymore.

Why's this happening?  My intention was to delete git from my project so I can start fresh and switch over to BitBucket.

How would I get rid of the list of projects that aren't on my GitHub account anymore?

```
user:mywebsite user$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .idea/workspace.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../BackAtIt/
        ../Dendro/
        ../NumberTracker/
        ../Something/
        ../ThisApp/
        ../WeBack/
        ../albums/
        ../auth/
        ../canvasgame/
        ../challenge/
        ../flights/
        ../free/
        ../myowntest/
        ../p/
        ../package-lock.json
        ../pickups/
        ../pra/
        ../prac/
        ../react_express_starter/
        ../reactexpress/
        ../rn-course/
        ../saga/
        ../securetext/
        ../storage/
        ../takehometest/
        ../tech_stack/
        ../tictactoe/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
user:mywebsite user$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .idea/workspace.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../BackAtIt/
        ../Dendro/
        ../NumberTracker/
        ../Something/
        ../ThisApp/
        ../WeBack/
        ../albums/
        ../auth/
        ../canvasgame/
        ../challenge/
        ../flights/
        ../free/
        ../myowntest/
        ../p/
        ../package-lock.json
        ../pickups/
        ../pra/
        ../prac/
        ../react_express_starter/
        ../reactexpress/
        ../rn-course/
        ../saga/
        ../securetext/
        ../storage/
        ../takehometest/
        ../tech_stack/
        ../tictactoe/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
user:mywebsite user$ git reset HEAD --hard
HEAD is now at 9127422 ??
user:mywebsite user$ git reset HEAD --hard
HEAD is now at 9127422 ??
user:mywebsite user$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../BackAtIt/
        ../Dendro/
        ../NumberTracker/
        ../Something/
        ../ThisApp/
        ../WeBack/
        ../albums/
        ../auth/
        ../canvasgame/
        ../challenge/
        ../flights/
        ../free/
        ../myowntest/
        ../p/
        ../package-lock.json
        ../pickups/
        ../pra/
        ../prac/
        ../react_express_starter/
        ../reactexpress/
        ../rn-course/
        ../saga/
        ../securetext/
        ../storage/
        ../takehometest/
        ../tech_stack/
        ../tictactoe/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
user:mywebsite user$
```

Comment: I think you have a `.git` folder in a parent or ancestor directory.

Comment: @Dai I see.  Generally, where can I locate this?

Comment: Please post the output of `git status` that gives you the surprising output, and please post a copy of your directory tree structure back to the root. What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: @Dai I posted the output of `git status`.  I'm using Mac OS via Terminal.  I'm not sure how to post a copy of directory tree structure back to the root.

Comment: [`git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---absolute-git-dir), `--show-toplevel`.